# How to self query the table and add column based on logic?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `tblplayer` and `tblTransaction` with schema:

Table: *tblplayer*

```
playerId   firstName    lastName
   3         John        Clark
   5          Mc        Donalds
   7         Stef         Joe
```

Table: *tblvirtualmoneytransactions*

```
source    sourceId    destination    destinationId    amount
   3        31            4             5              0.000
   4         3            6             7              20.000
   4         3            6             5              21.000
```

I need to prepare 4 columns `playerName`, `tblvirtualmoneytransactions.amount`, `tblvirtualmoneytransactions.destinationId` and `status`.

I have managed to get first 3 columns `playerName`, `tblvirtualmoneytransactions.amount`, `tblvirtualmoneytransactions.destinationId` with Query and condition:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT concat(tblplayer.firstName, ' ', tblplayer.lastName) FROM tblplayer WHERE tblplayer.playerId=tvm.destinationId) as playerName, 
tvm.amount as amount,
tvm.destinationId as destinationId
FROM tblvirtualmoneytransactions tvm WHERE tvm.source=4 AND tvm.destination=6 AND tvm.sourceId=3;
```

Result:

```
playerName   amount    destinationId
Mc Donalds    21           5
Stef Joe      20           7
```

From the above result, I need to get forth column `status` from the same query with the conditions:

```
status would be 1, IF the tvm2.source=3 AND tvm2.destination=4 AND tvm2.destinationId=tvm.destinationId.
```

But I am having trouble getting value for the fourth column.

I have a SQLfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a226e/2) ready as well if needed.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to use a subquery just to call `CONCAT()`

Comment: Your code contains only tvm and not tvm2, so possibly you need a self join. Clarify what you want and provide expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a correlated subquery when a `JOIN` will work.

You can use a self-LEFT JOIN to match up with rows with the other condition. Then you can test whether this finds a match using a `NULL` test.

```
SELECT CONCAT(p.firstName, ' ', p.lastName) AS playerName,
    tvm.amount, tvm.destinationId,
    tvm2.destinationId IS NOT NULL AS status
FROM tblvirtualmoneytransactions AS tvm
JOIN tblplayer AS p ON p.playerId=tvm.destinationId
LEFT JOIN tblvirtualmoneytransactions AS tvm2 
    ON tvm.destinationId = tvm2.destinationId AND tvm2.source=3 AND tvm2.destination=4
WHERE tvm.source=4 AND tvm.destination=6 AND tvm.sourceId=3
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a226e/12)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.